# BlackBerry : How to detect memory leaks in QNX Momentics IDE

Tags: memory-leaks, blackberry-10, blackberry-qnx

I am developing the game on BlackBerry platform with help of QNX Momentics IDE but unfortunately it is `crash randomly`. I want to `check any memory leaks` in project. How to achieve this? Is their any tool for that?

Any suggestion always appreciated.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

There are profiling tools available on the Momentics IDE
https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/bb10/com.qnx.doc.ide.userguide/topic/profiler_base_.html